# Datepicker in Oracle APEX 20.1 modal dialog

Tags: jquery, css, oracle-apex

In Oracle-Apex 20.1 I have a modal dialog with two fields, one textfield and one datepicker.
There is a problem with displaying datepicker. When I'm opening it is displaying in IFRAME. How can I display it on IFrame, that there will be no problem with scrolling in this modal dialog.

for non-apex users page looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div role="dialog">
            <iframe>
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <div id="ui-datepicker-div">
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: That is APEX default behavior can you explain what do you need.

Comment: This modal dialog is small I want to display datapicker on top of view. Now is inside Iframe

Comment: I can write an example with HTML5 input if you want to try

Comment: It could be perfect, Thank you very much

Comment: I wrote an answer but I'm not sure if it will work, although why do you open the modal in an iframe?

Comment: It's not my decision. Oracle APEX is build in that way unfortunately.

Comment: You can change the height of a modal.

Comment: Yea that's what i did, but it's not a solution, it looks weird with so many empty space

Comment: Try to recreate the problem on Oracle APEX live